# Не загружается Ubuntu 18, snapd

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot

Включил сегодня ПК, а система остановилась по загрузке и в консоль пишет:

```
Started Wait until snapd is fully seeded
```

и дальше не грузится. Вы с таким сталкивались? Подскажите, пожалуйста, как решить проблему?

Comment: Форматните диск и переустановите заново.

Comment: Гениально! Как же я не подумал сразу

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1051762/long-boot-delay-on-ubuntu-loading-splash-screen-following-regular-dist-upgrade-o

Comment: Ох уж этот snap. Я после установки системы в первую очередь делаю `sudo apt purge snap* apport* tracker*` - самые бесполезные и проблемные пакеты в убунту, имхо.